# Cannot GET /POST? error in express?

Tags: node.js, express, web, get

I have a very simple express code

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var http = require("http");
var path = require("path");

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.set("views",path.resolve(__dirname,"views"));
app.set("view engine","ejs");

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.render("index");
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log("posted!");
    res.render("final");
});



http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
```

Now when I try visiting localhost:3000 everything loads fine, in index.ejs I have a simple form with a input having a name mname, whan i hit a name in the input box and press enter I get This error

```
Cannot GET /POST?mname=a
```

I defined a app.post in the code, and asked it to render final.ejs. So where is the code going wrong?

tried other questions saying that express  4 users "router" for routing, tried that but also failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not include the ejs file with the form you want to submit, but from the error you get it seems you are not doing a `POST` request, but instead a `GET` request to path `/POST`. This is a completely different thing.

I guess in the form you have something like:

```
 <form action='POST'>
```

but instead you need something like:

```
<form action='/' method='POST'>
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had a similar problem and I solved it because I forgot to include the app.get for my /post link.